# Is it possible to customize Terminator's prompt / hostname (user@domain) colors?

Tags: colors, prompt, hostname, terminator

So far I have not seen anything on customizing the Terminator "prompt" colors.

I know it is possible through `~/.bashrc` but this is overridden by Terminator. Is there a way to either customize Terminator's colors further or force it to use customized bashrc colors?

If neither of these are possible, can I at least bold it? The reason is to make each user execution clearly standout when outputs are lengthy.

Comment: Edit: Apparently .bashrc is the way to customize. Terminator does use the setting. I just needed to uncomment "force color" and use "source" to refresh the setting in the terminal.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 30):

Open **~/.bashrc** and uncomment

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

by removing the hash:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

The colors should appear then.

**Note**: don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` or restart your terminal.

[image: 'Before' Screenshot]

[image: 'After' Screenshot]